# How to add one nanosecond to a timestamp in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to add a nanosecond to a `timestamp` variable without any luck.

This is the example code:

```
DECLARE
  lts_nextTimestamp TIMESTAMP = TO_TIMESTAMP('11-11-2013 22:10:10:111111111');
  ;
BEGIN
  lts_nextTimestamp := lts_nextTimestamp + 1 / (10000000*60*60*24)
END;
```

Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't imagine why you would want to do this. If you need to save a timestamp of a record, use the true (current) value. If you need to order the records that happened simultaneously, use separate seq_no field.

Comment: I need it for a paging system ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`interval day to second` literal can be used to add fractional seconds to a timestamp value:

In this example we add one nanosecond:

```
select timestamp '2013-11-11 22:10:10.111111111' + 
       interval '0 00:00:00.000000001' day to second(9) as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES                           
-------------------------------
11-NOV-13 10.10.10.111111112 PM
```

**Note**: When you are using `to_timestamp()` function to convert character literal to a value of timestamp data type, it's a good idea to specify a format mask(not relay on NLS settings).

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('11-11-2013 22:10:10:111111111', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9') + 
       interval '0 00:00:00.000000001' day to second(9) as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES                           
-------------------------------
11-NOV-13 10.10.10.111111112 PM
```

**Note**: As you intend to process values of timestamp data type using PL/SQL you should be aware of the following. The default precision of fractional seconds for values of timestamp data type, in PL/SQL, is 6 not 9 as it is in SQL, so you may expect truncation of fractional second. In order to avoid truncation of fractional seconds use `timestamp_unconstrained` and `dsinterval_unconstrained` data types instead of `timestamp` and `interval day to second`:

```
declare
  l_tmstmp timestamp_unconstrained := to_timestamp('11-11-2013 22:10:10:111111111',
                                                   'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9');
  l_ns     dsinterval_unconstrained :=  interval '0.000000001' second;
begin
  l_tmstmp := l_tmstmp + l_ns;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_tmstmp, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9'));
end;
```

Result:

```
anonymous block completed
11-11-2013 22:10:10:111111112
```

Comment: A slightly shorter way would be: `interval '0.000000001' second`.